# How to split a stream by pauses

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs

I have a stream of similar events and want to split it by proximity in time: every event that follows the previous one in, let's say, less than 5 minutes, must go into one chain where I can mark then the beginning and end of this chain. All in real time, no bufferization.

Like this (`-` denotes pause less than 5 min, `=` denotes 5 min time span):

```
a - a - a = a - a - a =-- a - a - a
B           EB         E  B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `windowWhen` + `timeoutWith` operators to accomplish this:

```
let sharedSource = source.share();

sharedSource.windowWhen(() =>   
  sharedSource.timeoutWith(5 * 60 * 60, Observable.empty()).ignoreElements())
.subscribe(window => {
  window.subscribe(/*Handle items in the stream*/);
});
```

The above builds an `Observable` of `Observables` or `windows`, each window is made of elements that are at most 5 minutes apart.

Comment: Thank you. Just for those who still use Rx.js 4. The equivalent is:
`let sharedSource = source.share();

sharedSource.window(() =>   
  sharedSource.timeout(5 * 60 * 60, Rx.Observable.empty()).ignoreElements())
.subscribe(window => {
  window.subscribe(/*Handle items in the stream*/);
});`